# What programming language was Spelunky HD written in?

Tags: spelunky-hd, spelunky

I know the original Spelunky was written in the Game Maker language. (developed by YoyoGames, with the .gmk file extension)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spelunky HD was written in C++, using Direct X for graphics, FMOD for sound and some Xbox specific libraries for... Xbox things.

[Source is from a Q&A by the author.](http://new.spring.me/#!/AndyHull/q/393510012112093692?utm_source=social)